# A usable solution for console output capturing - java

Tags: java, console

I am making a program that will have the ability to run the java compiler and jvm right from within it (Don't ask me why I am reinventing the wheel, if your reply does not help, save it, I am already quite frustrated spending hours on solutions that do not work!). So far I have managed it to track whenever I input something in my textField that starts with java so that it will actually wrap up the text and give it a run like so:

```
    if(String.valueOf(object).startsWith("java")){
        try{
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec(String.valueOf(object));
        }
        catch(Exception e){gsc.mainWindow.printf("error");}
```

Consider `gsc.mainWindow.printf(...);` my output to a JTextArea within a JFrame.

What I have managed now is to run the commands, but anything fails I shall be able to print it directly to my output. I know this has been answered a ton of times before, read about 10 ways to do this, but none of them worked or was understandable to the point that I could run it. I need the code to be simple enough as this will have to be outputting what the proccess will be writing in the default system's Console (cmd,terminal) and then stop (I thought that this can be a method call alltogether). I am quite bad with this kind of stuff, even a multithread solution could fit my needs, nothing too professional really, I just need it to work. Any information you need, ask away!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: so you want to launch an external program, capture it's output for use in your application, and also print the output to standard output?

Comment: I want to launch only java virtual machine and java compiler externally, capture the output for my application and I don't really mind if it is printed in standard output, though I don't need it! (If I have to print to both, so be it, that is the least of my troubles)

Comment: I'm confused about what is not working for you though. Are you reading from `process.getInputStream()` to get what the launched command is outputting?

Comment: Even if I do get the Input Stream of the Proccess how on earth will I make it print on my JTextArea?  I have tried solutions found both here and in other websites and managed to do nothing at all! :/ If you have a snippet of code that can help me make the stream print in my JTextArea (and that works) post it in an answer! I would be glad to check it! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with Swing (assuming that's what JTextArea is) but usually you would just loop over the inputStream, reading it in line-by-line (or character by character) and send the data wherever you want. For example https://gist.github.com/3723290

Comment: Gonna check it out as soon as I can! ;)

Comment: @matt b Didn't capture any output at all... I used the code exactly as it is and I got no output whatsoever... Is it possible that I have done something worng elsewhere? Like I have to do something else...? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know you if you want to read this, but you know, in the Java world, you should always look for a solution before implementing your own. And the solution for common problems, most of the time, comes from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) or other Apache projects. Saying that everything but your solution doesn't work or is too complicated to you will only cost you time and money (and your job, eventually).

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) is what you need to solve your problem faster and easier.

---- Edit ----

Here is some code of how to capture the output of the child process. There's a class just for it, the [PumpStreamHandler](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/PumpStreamHandler.html):

```
DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler();
exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

CommandLine commandline = CommandLine.parse(command);  //where command is your command line
exec.execute(commandline);
```

---- Edit 2 ----

Here is the copy-paste solution you want to capture the message using an `OutputStream`:

```
public abstract class LogOutputStream extends OutputStream {

protected static final String LINE_SEPERATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH = 2048;

protected boolean hasBeenClosed = false;
protected byte[] buf;
protected int count;
private int bufLength;

public LogOutputStream() {
    bufLength = DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    buf = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    count = 0;
}

public void close() {
    flush();
    hasBeenClosed = true;
}

public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
    if (hasBeenClosed) {
        throw new IOException("The stream has been closed.");
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (count == bufLength) {
        final int newBufLength = bufLength + DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
        final byte[] newBuf = new byte[newBufLength];

        System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newBuf, 0, bufLength);

        buf = newBuf;
        bufLength = newBufLength;
    }
    buf[count] = (byte) b;
    count++;
}

public void flush() {
    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (count == LINE_SEPERATOR.length()) {
        if (((char) buf[0]) == LINE_SEPERATOR.charAt(0)
                && ((count == 1) ||
                ((count == 2) && ((char) buf[1]) == LINE_SEPERATOR.charAt(1)))) {
            reset();
            return;
        }
    }
    final byte[] theBytes = new byte[count];
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, theBytes, 0, count);
    log(new String(theBytes));
    reset();
}


private void reset() {
    count = 0;
}

public abstract void log(String message);
}
```

Then just create a subclass of it, implement the `public void log(String message)` with the code that updates the UI, and it's done.

Comment: I dont like external packages in general, but I have faced so many problems implementing features lately, that this might seem like a good idea right about now. I will give it a check and inform you! Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you support me with some code here? Trying to find how to do this, seems like a very good package to solve my problem, however I cannot get a usable example to build my code from! :S

Comment: Works like a charm but it only displays output to the original Windows console (cmd), how can I pipe it to my JTextArea? Shall I make a BufferedReader? (First Time working with Apache Commons, sorry for my noobishness! :$ )

Comment: Use [this constructor](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/PumpStreamHandler.html#PumpStreamHandler%28java.io.OutputStream%29) of the PumpStreamHandler to set your own OutputStream (which you can use to redirect the messages to your UI).

Comment: Uhm, I know I could read from an InputStream, but how do I handle the OutputStream? I mean do I use a writer? Because a reader is not working for it obviously... (Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this topic, but can't really figure it out...)

Comment: I was not online for a while, but now that I see this, you just saved the day! Thanks a lot for your help and patience! :)