# Java-How to extend InputStream to read from a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, inputstream, jtextfield

Working on a project I got into running java applications through a small console-like window. Thanks to the wonderful community in here I managed to [solve the problem with outputting the data from a proccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427981/1650200) but my command-line applications running will constantly give errors as there is no input stream.

Based on the last helpful reply in that thread I suppose I shall approach similarly the `JTextFieldInputStream extends InputStream` implementation, but looking in the javadocs and throughout google and the internet for some class that does just that I really found nothing explaining how to do this.

So I am asking for some link, example, tutorial, sample code for it just like in the previous topic.
Give me just a class that extends InputStream and can be extended to read from a JTextField when I press Enter and I will do the rest with implementing this and making it work! Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry I'm confused, is your application command line-based or window-based?

Comment: Window based. It is running command line-based .class files from within it e.g. it will call a proccess `java HelloWorldInput` which is command line-based and needs input that I hopefully can retrieve from a JTextField in my application. I cannot provide code, it is about 6 files and a total of 500+ lines of code... :/

Comment: where from are you supposed to take the input, the JTextField or the console and anyway, why would you need an inputstream to read from a JTextField? why not go the easier way?

Comment: My JTextField is observable for a couple of reasons, so apparently when Enter is pressed strange things happen already! :P I am supposed to redirect the inutstream of the process to a subclass of inputstream I need someone to help me with so that the input is taken from the JTextField instead of the console. If you have an easier way (is it listeners anyway?) give me a hint.. :)

Comment: What's wrong with `InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myTextField.getText().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this implementation

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class JTextFieldInputStream extends InputStream {
    byte[] contents;
    int pointer = 0;

    public JTextFieldInputStream(final JTextField text) {

        text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyChar()=='\n'){
                    contents = text.getText().getBytes();
                    pointer = 0;
                    text.setText("");
                }
                super.keyReleased(e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(pointer >= contents.length) return -1;
        return this.contents[pointer++];
    }

}
```

to use this input stream, do the following

```
 InputStream in = new JTextFieldInputStream( someTextField );
 char c;
 while( (c = in.read()) != -1){
    //do whatever with c
 }
```

> does it read only when I hit enter?

it reads when you call `in.read()` if the return value `-1` it means end of the stream

> (And will I be able to modify so that the Enter key empties the JTextField?)

you need to add an action listener and this functionality has nothing to do with the job of input stream

Comment: Is it easy to modify so that the InputStream is externally designed to use the JTextField? It gets quite frustrating to change the code and my JTextField is already an observable for some other stuff so if you could modify this a little... :)

Comment: I did not understand what you mean exactly, however, I made some changes to the InputStream to be more stable.

Comment: Now this is pretty straightforward, gonna check it out, thanks a ton for the help with this. By the way does it read only when I hit enter? (And will I be able to modify so that the Enter key empties the JTextField?) :D

Comment: Whatever questions you have ask me. I can help and even provide some code for my TextField if that is what you need!

Comment: well, if you want the input stream to be dynamic it is hard a little bit. should the pointer go back to zero once the text has been edited?

Comment: I want the text to be edited freely but when Enter is pressed the Field empties, the Stream gets the data and passess it to the process (apparently passing it will happen throughout apache commons' PumpStreamHandler so no problem there). So yes the pointer goes to zero and if I get it correctly it also sets the text of the TextField to `""`.

Comment: Ok the listener is just a simple tweak to my existing one then. So to sum up and go check it: I shall tweak my listener to call in.read and clear the field and the rest is going to work as it is. And the return value is -1 when Enter is hit with an empty JTextField, right?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but never tested it. So, if it fails you should not be mad at me

Comment: For all your trouble I could never be mad at you, I can only be thankful that you spent a while to help me out! :)

Comment: @HussainAl-Mutawa `KeyListener` is a very low-level API. There are several alternatives that are better to use for a JTextField such as: `ActionListener` (if all you care is when user presses "Enter"), `DocumentListener` (if you want to know when the text is modified) or use KeyBindings if you want to add a very specific behaviour to your textfield

Comment: You know what guys, your help is invaluable but there is much more of a problem to this than I possibly imagined. I wanted to run cmd-line applications through a GUI and I just found out that this will require me to tweak code from the applications as well replacing Console and System.in which will beat the purpose of the exercise, so anyways thanks a ton for the time and help, I will be able to use this later on in my system for something else hopefully (btw it's fully stable and fine) but running cmd-line apps through a GUI is something I cannot simulate probably! -.-

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, but @Spiritios said that he doesn't want to use ActionListener. but I think **DocumentListener** should be used

Comment: I had the same problem when I wanted to use an assembler simulator in my UI, the way I did it is by adding an InputStreamListener. the assembler can have a read() command which requires the user input. check this http://mutawaprojs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Java/Compiler/src/nz/ac/massey/compiler/simulator/GiovanniSimulator.java

Answer (score 10):

What I don't understand if why you need a JTextField that extends InputStream? Basically, what you are looking for is:

1. Add an `ActionListener` on the `JTextField` (ie, when use presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `actionPerformed` will be invoked)
2. You need to grab the `text` of the JTextField using `getText()`
3. You can then "transform" the `String text` to an `InputStream` with `new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Here is a small snippet that should get you the basic idea:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextField {

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTextField.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
        textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String text = textfield.getText();
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    // Here do something with your input stream (something non-blocking)
                    System.err.println(text);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textfield);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextField().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Now there is a problem with ActionListener as I have another one for another purpose so basically when I call an external process from apache commons exec I need an InputStream to pass to it so that it will be able to read some data from somewhere. So apparently ActionListener is not what I am looking for... except if I am overlooking anything...

Comment: @Spiritios Havaing multiple ActionListener is not a problem. It is also possible that the ActionListener you have, is actually the same as the one I am mentionning in my answer. I am almost 99% sure that this is the way to go, so you are probably overlooking ;-).

Comment: Hmmm ok... But I am using Apache Commons PumpStreamHandler and basically I need an InputStream for it that will be passed to the constructor in order to be used by the subprocess I call so can this be done using Listeners really?? :O

Comment: @Spiritios I added a sample code that should give you the basic idea on how to go. In the action listener, you can call your Apache commons pumpstreamhandler etc...

Comment: This is the much better answer to the original question.