# Getting and using an application's passed InputStream

Tags: java, apache, swing, inputstream, event-dispatch-thread

Recently I was trying to implement the functionality of a normal terminal to a graphically designed Swing-based console project. I love how some people in here made this possible, but yet I stumbled upon another big kind of problem. Some people actually spoke about `InpuStreamListener` although I am not too fond of this. A sample code of my work (pretty much not exactly mine, but it is the source code of my app) would be the following:

```
// Making an executor
org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor exec = new org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor();
// Creating the streams (pretty much ignore this, I just include it as a general idea of the method)
consoleOutputStream = new ConsoleOutputStream();
consoleInputStream = new JTextFieldInputStream(gsc.mainWindow.getConsoleInput().getJTextField());
// Stream Handler with the customized streams I use for the process
org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler(consoleOutputStream, consoleOutputStream, consoleInputStream);
// Setting the handler and finally making command line and executing
exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine commandline = org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine.parse(String.valueOf(arg));  
            exec.execute(commandline);
```

Now the thing is I generally try to run java application through the java commands through this method. `OutputStream` works really fine, no flaws whatsoever and gives me all it shall, but applications with Input give me a lot of trouble. I beieve the problem resides in the hardcoding to `System.in`, the `Scanner` class, the `Console` class etc. So here's what I need some help with (finally):
I want to either be able to directly access the `InputStream` passed to my application or someone explaining a way to me of how to actually write an `InputStreamListener` that will occasionaly be used when I run external java applications (yes, I run them through my interface instead of cmd or terminal, I am trying to make a tool here). If this is too complicated, needs a lot of tweaking on my side or is generally quite impossible, can someone help me just to get the passed `InputStream` so I can actually write a class that will allow me to write applications specific to my interface?

Thanks in advance and thanks really even for putting the time to read this whole text! :)

Comment: Whoever knows why the `event-dispatch-thread` tag was edited in by @mKorbel, can they explain it? Thanks! :)

Comment: all event to the AWT, Swing GUI must be done on Event dispatch Tread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these Apache libraries implement the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` interfaces, you can use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` to access information.  Here's a quick example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputRedirection extends Box{

    public InputRedirection() {
        super(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

        //Remap input
        //Create the input stream to be used as standard in
        final PipedInputStream pisIN = new PipedInputStream();
        //Create an end so we can put info into standard in
        PipedOutputStream posIN = new PipedOutputStream();
        //Wrap with a writer (for ease of use)
        final BufferedWriter standardIn = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(posIN));
        //Set standard in to use this stream
        System.setIn(pisIN);

        //Connect the pipes
        try {
            pisIN.connect(posIN);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }        

        //UI element where we're entering standard in
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        ActionListener sendText = new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    //Transfering the text to the Standard Input stream
                    standardIn.append(field.getText());
                    standardIn.flush();
                    field.setText("");
                    field.requestFocus();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }};

        field.addActionListener(sendText);
        add(field);

        //Why not - now it looks like a real messaging system
        JButton button = new JButton("Send");
        button.addActionListener(sendText);
        add(button);

        //Something using standard in
        //Prints everything from standard in to standard out.
        Thread standardInReader = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean update = false;
                final StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
                while(true){
                    try {

                        BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
                        while(stream.available() > 0){
                            int charCode = stream.read();
                            s.append(Character.toChars(charCode));
                            update = true;
                        }
                        if(update){
                            //Print whatever was retrieved from standard in to standard out.
                            System.out.println(s.toString());
                            s.delete(0, s.length());
                            update = false;
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            }});
        standardInReader.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new InputRedirection());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Oh - and one thing to think about when using PipedStreams:  Only one thread can write to the Output and only one can read from the input.  Otherwise you get some funky problems (see http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/whats-this-ioexception-write-end-dead/ for more details).

Comment: You got me wrong: my `consoleOutputStream` is an extension of the `OutputStream` that already works and prints the output of the application that is hardcoded inside the application to print in `System.out`. This functionality is exactly what I need in reverse for the `InputStream` extension that is fitted within my `consoleInputStream` variable. Basically I only want to work with the InputStream, the Output is fine already and piping is not my best bet, I suppose that an `InputStreamListener` which was previously suggested could do it but still not the optimal thing for my needs... :/

Comment: Previously is http://stackoverflow.com/a/12669494/1650200 where the class written in this post is the type of object that `consoleInputStream` is. What I need is a way to use this class so that it really works as an input class that will work for any java application whatsoever. Piping seems a bit too clumsy as far as I will already be running a java app within another java app and threads may easily get messed if not careful, so I would like more of an optimal solution to this if there even is one! Thanks anyway and I appreciate your suggestion! :)

Comment: Yes - redirecting System.in is done virtually the same way, only backwards.  I used System.out because it was easier to demonstrate.  I'll update my example with System.in as I have time.  As far as the threading goes, the Pipes aren't too hard to use/prevent from getting mixed up - I doubt it would be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I will try using pipes when you update your example, seems fairly easy and with the right reading around the net I will probably not mess it up! :)

Comment: Example is now updated to redirect `System.in`.  One thing that caught me for a while is flushing your buffers (make sure you do it).