# How to set JTextArea as InputStream for jython interpreter?

Tags: java, inputstream, jython, jtextarea

I found this link
[Java-How to extend InputStream to read from a JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669368/java-how-to-extend-inputstream-to-read-from-a-jtextfield)
but it says it's just for `JTextField` (but also) I tried it changing the `JTextField` datatype as `JTextArea` but it didn't do anything and it had error

thank you in advance!

---

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author JoJuJa
 */
public class JythonInterpreter extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JythonInterpreter
     */
    public JythonInterpreter() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Source.py");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Compile");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 108, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            PrintStream stdout = System.out;
            TextAreaOutputStream taOutput = new TextAreaOutputStream(jTextArea2);
            TextAreaInputStream taInput = new TextAreaInputStream(jTextArea2);
            PythonInterpreter coder = new PythonInterpreter();
            coder.setOut(taOutput);
            coder.setErr(taOutput);
            coder.setIn(taInput);
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(taOutput));
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(taOutput));
            System.setIn(taInput);
            coder.exec(jTextArea1.getText());
            System.setOut(stdout);
            System.setErr(stdout);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JythonInterpreter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JythonInterpreter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JythonInterpreter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JythonInterpreter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JythonInterpreter().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    // End of variables declaration                   }
```

the code above was the project in Netbeans it only has the 2 textarea and a button that has the actions

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class TextAreaInputStream extends InputStream {
    byte[] contents;
    int pointer = 0;

    public TextAreaInputStream(final JTextArea text) {

        text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyChar()=='\n'){
                    contents = text.getText().getBytes();
                    pointer = 0;
                    text.setText("");
                }
                super.keyReleased(e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(pointer >= contents.length) return -1;
        return this.contents[pointer++];
    }

}
```

and the code above is the modified TextAreaInputStream.java class from the link [Java-How to extend InputStream to read from a JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669368/java-how-to-extend-inputstream-to-read-from-a-jtextfield)

[This is the interface and output that was generated when i entered the code in the "Source.py" textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXG4X.png)

hope you can help me. I don't know what to put correctly in the read() function in the TextAreaInputStream.java class in the line 30, that was said in the error message in the output text area.

Comment: Sit back a minute and re-evaluate which information other users need to understand the problem you're facing. What is missing in your question? What might be helpful to understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm having trouble with understanding the read() function in the inputstream class. I just copied and integrated the code to my project from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669368/java-how-to-extend-inputstream-to-read-from-a-jtextfield .